# Using a library in an SDK and my own project

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, loopj

I'm using an SDK in my project which is using loopj and importing it through it's own gradle file with `compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'`. I'm also using loopj and importing it through my apps gradle file with `compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'`.

That's giving me a lot of warnings, when building the project. Is it possible to compile it just in one gradle file and use it in both, my app and the sdk?

**Edit:**

The good old 'turn it off and on again' did it for me. After restarting Android Studio all warnings disappeared..

Comment: post your warnings and show build.gradle

Comment: Solved with restarting android studio.. thanks anyway!

Comment: Glad to hear. Move ahead